# Complete the Number Sequence Series

Tags: number-sequence

I have tried to find the next number in this series but I'm stumped.

The series is:

> 61,52,63,94 .....

Can anybody figure out the next number?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the numbers? :-)

Comment: No, Well I got this.

Comment: next word or digit, make up your mind ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @CarlLondahl mentioned, the trick to this one is

> To reverse the digits

Which gives us

> 16,25,36,49 which is ofcourse 4^2,5^2,6^2,7^2

So the next element is

> The digits of 8^2 reversed -> **46**

Comment: That's the correct answer.